# How to get quote details in helper

Tags: cart, session, quote, quoteitem

I want to see if there is anything exists in the cart if I am in a phtml page

I have tried to use session and cart but I am getting null 
When I tried to use session I wasn’t sure how to get the quote ID in order to get cart ID but I don’t know which is the right approach to take 
Could anyone help me out with this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

app/code/Xigen/Cart/Helper/Quote.php

```php
namespace Xigen\Cart\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Quote extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getAllVisibleItems() {
        return $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    }

    public function getAllVisibleItemsCount() {
        return count($this->getAllVisibleItems());
    }
}
```

Then in template for example

`$visibleItems = $this->helper('\Xigen\Cart\Helper\Quote')->getAllVisibleItemsCount();`

Comment: How does it know to take the active cart?  I mean for each customer a different cart.

Comment: It's always only the cart of the current session.  Unless the block is cached of course.

Comment: I was about to say the session as well. @DominicXigen thank you for this I will take a look at this and get back to you. Thanks for showing the count part

Comment: @DominicXigen  hi there. I have tried this it worked for maybe once like it did work but then when I refresh the page it won’t come up like it’s null but my cart has product

Comment: Can you disable frontend caches and see if still the same `php bin/magento cache:disable layout block_html full_page`